# Pushing items from a funciton into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

So I have a small RPG im coding (well I started it ages ago and gave up but have just come back for naother look!). I have a main character (just one so far):

```
var heroes = [{
  name: 'Mary',
  health: 15,
  weapon: 'sword',
  damage: 8,
  dodge: 8,
  backpack: 'water',
  experience: 5
}];
```

Can I add extra items to the backpack or as I suspect (the below) is this the wrong way of storing the information as I get an error.

```
backpack: 'water', 'bread', 'cheese',
```

Secondly and related... I have a function to fight an enemy. When it is defeated the content of their backpack would be pushed to the hero's backpack. I thought something like the below would work, but again Im clearly wrong :)

All help gratefully accepted :)

Full code:

```
<h1>
<b>RPG Battle</b>
</h1>

<p><button id="fight">Fight</button><button id="reset">Reset</button></p>
<div id="output"></div>


<script>
var enemies = [{
    name: 'Wizard',
    health: 10,
    weapon: 'his staff.',
    damage: 12,
    dodge: 10,
    backpack: 'Cloak of Invisibility....'
  },
  {
    name: 'Elf',
    health: 4,
    weapon: 'a dagger.',
    damage: 6,
    dodge: 8,
    backpack: 'a bow & Arrow....'
  },
  {
    name: 'Dragon',
    health: 20,
    weapon: 'a fireball.',
    damage: 15,
    dodge: 2,
    backpack: 'a golden key...'
  },
  {
    name: 'Goblin',
    health: 12,
    weapon: 'his bow and arrow....',
    damage: 4,
    dodge: 6,
    backpack: 'gold coins....'
  },
  {
    name: 'Dwarf',
    health: 7,
    weapon: 'his axe.',
    damage: 5,
    dodge: 4,
    backpack: 'a treasure map....'
  },
  {
    name: 'Orc',
    health: 8,
    weapon: 'a sword.',
    damage: 5,
    dodge: 5,
    backpack: 'a silver tooth....'
  },
  {
    name: 'Witch',
    health: 6,
    weapon: 'her potion of the undead....',
    damage: 7,
    dodge: 6,
    backpack: 'a potion of the living....'
  },
  {
    name: 'Old Lady',
    health: 3,
    weapon: 'her frying pan.',
    damage: 1,
    dodge: 1,
    backpack: 'some fruit and vegetables....'
  },
  {
    name: 'Villagers',
    health: 15,
    weapon: 'sharpened sticks.',
    damage: 5,
    dodge: 1,
    backpack: 'some meat....'
  },
  {
    name: 'Thief',
    health: 4,
    weapon: 'his fists.',
    damage: 3,
    dodge: 9,
    backpack: 'a bag of jewels....'
  }
];

var heroes = [{
  name: 'Mary',
  health: 15,
  weapon: 'sword',
  damage: 8,
  dodge: 8,
  backpack: '',
  experience: 5
}];

function getRandomElement(list) {
  return Object.create(list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)]);
}

function getRandomEnemy() {
  return getRandomElement(enemies);
}

function getRandomHero() {
  return getRandomElement(heroes);
}

var x, randomEnemy, hero;

var output = document.getElementById("output");
var fightBtn = document.getElementById("fight");
var resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset");

fightBtn.addEventListener("click", battle);

function reset() {
  x = 1;
  randomEnemy = getRandomEnemy();
  fightBtn.disabled = false; 
  hero = getRandomHero();
  output.innerHTML = "";
}

resetBtn.addEventListener("click", reset);

reset();

function battle() { 
  if (hero.health <= 0 || randomEnemy.health <= 0) {
    fightBtn.disabled = true;
    return;
  }
  
  var enemyDamage = Math.floor((Math.random() * (randomEnemy.damage)) + 1);
  var enemyDodge = Math.floor((Math.random() * (randomEnemy.dodge)) + 1);
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 1;
  var heroDodge = [Math.floor(Math.random() * hero.dodge)];
  var heroDamage = Math.floor((Math.random() * hero.damage) + 1);
  var heroExperience = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

  output.innerHTML += "<br>" + "<b>" + "Round " + x++ + "</b>";
  output.innerHTML += "<br>" + "The " + randomEnemy.name + " attacks you with " + randomEnemy.weapon;
    
  if (randomNumber < heroDodge) {
    output.innerHTML += "<br>" + "You evade the attack!";
  } else if (hero.health > 0) {
    hero.health = hero.health - enemyDamage;
    if (hero.health < 0)
      hero.health = 0;
    output.innerHTML += "<br>" + "The " + randomEnemy.name + " did " + enemyDamage + " damage";
    output.innerHTML += "<br>" + "You have " + hero.health + " health remaining.";
  }
    
  if (hero.health <= 0) {
    output.innerHTML += "<br>" + "You have been killed by the " + randomEnemy.name;
    fightBtn.disabled = true;
    return;
  } else {
    output.innerHTML += "<br>" + hero.name + " attacks the " + randomEnemy.name + " with their " + hero.weapon;
  }
    
  if (randomNumber < enemyDodge) {
    output.innerHTML += "<br>" + "The " + randomEnemy.name + " evades the attack!";
  } else if (randomEnemy.health > 0) {
    randomEnemy.health = randomEnemy.health - heroDamage;
    if (randomEnemy.health < 0)
     randomEnemy.health = 0;
    output.innerHTML += "<br>" + hero.name + " did " + heroDamage + " damage";
    output.innerHTML += "<br>" + "The " + randomEnemy.name + " has " + randomEnemy.health + " health";
  }
    
  if (randomEnemy.health <= 0) {
    output.innerHTML += "<br>" + "The " + randomEnemy.name + " dies! You find " + randomEnemy.backpack;
    output.innerHTML += "<br>"
    output.innerHTML += "<br>" + "You gain " + heroExperience + " XP";
    output.innerHTML += "<br>" + "You have " + hero.health + " health left";
    output.innerHTML += "<br>" + hero.backpack.push(randomEnemy.backpack);
    output.innerHTML += "<br>" + "Your backpack contains " + hero.backpack;

    fightBtn.disabled = true;
  }

}

</script>
```

Comment: arrays are in square brackets: `backpack: ['water', 'bread', 'cheese']`

Answer (score 0):

initialization of the hero should be:

```
  var heroes = [{
  name: 'Mary',
  health: 15,
  weapon: 'sword',
  damage: 8,
  dodge: 8,
  backpack: ['water', 'some other stuff'], //empty backpack is ['']
  experience: 5
}];
```

Now the backpack is an array you can push into.

Comment: No problem glad I could help.

Comment: I see you found the other issue. I only got one item I noticed so that went correct. Good luck further on with the game.

Comment: Thanks. Im a little unsure why exactly the square brackets need to be round the piece of code that they are. Can you give a technical explanation? :) ie. backpack.push([randomEnemy.backpack]);

Comment: The brackets go around it to push it in as an array, but reading back they are not needed (we would create an array in an array and that is not what you want). It should work without the brackets. Just tested a few things. Do you get an error if you try without the brackets?

Comment: Ahh I just noticed the problem. I'd coded: output.innerHTML += "<br>" + hero.backpack.push(randomEnemy.backpack); Like that was ever going to work! Idiot :)

Comment: Ah yes that is an important step. If my answers helped you can put it as "the correct" answer so people know the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

So after the replies above I managed to work out (guess) that the line reading:

```
output.innerHTML += "<br>" + hero.backpack.push(randomEnemy.backpack);
```

should be changed to:

```
output.innerHTML += "<br>" + hero.backpack.push([randomEnemy.backpack]);
```